# Drawable launcher icon not in other language (Android dev)

Tags: icons, drawable, launcher

The launcher icon can only be shown in language  `other` but not in like  `zh-HK` .
I have added e.g.  `drawable-hdip-zh-HK` and other folder with different resolution like  `drawable-mdip-zh-HK` .
This icon should always be showing on the top left hand corner of my app.

Any idea?

screen dump here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVIw3.jpg

Comment: Fixed: remove dimens.xml and styles.xml that manually copied to new created folder "value-zh-HK"